# Why does gatling report show different values in "Response Time Percentiles" Section and main report overview?

Tags: java, performance, gatling, latency, gatling-plugin

Consider this **gatling report overview**
[image]

As you can see, the max response time is shown as `18389 ms`. Now let's check response time percentiles section below.

[image]

I have zoomed into the max spiked section. Now as you can see, the max shown here is `1966 ms` which is different compared to the max shown in the overall overview at the top(which in our case was `18389 ms`.

So why is there a discrepancy between these two values? That too such a large difference(an order of 10^1).

Comment: Lookup the word "percentiles" in relation to "statistics" in mathematics !   It's not so much averages, as "groupings" (data) in particular "similar environment sets of(plural) results" (ad hoc vaguely).

Comment: No way to tell unless you share your `simulation.log` file.